# angular chartjs can't redraw onchange

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

I got a problem with angular chartjs,
at the normal state when I do `onInputChange()` the chart is not automated redraw. actually when I try to log `console.log(this.lineChartData);` it's working fine.
and also currently the chart is working fine but only when :

1. My position is google chrome console is opened, and I close it, so the chart will redraw
2. My position is google chrome closed and then after change I open the console, and it's working fine

but in normal state (withouth need open the console or close the console), it's not redraw

this my code

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart, ChartConfiguration, ChartEvent, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { default as Annotation } from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
import { faVolumeUp } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { HomeService } from '../_services/home.service';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})

export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  content?: string;
  isLoading: boolean = false;
  dataTranscriptionChart: any[] = [];
  dataTranscriptionSummaries: any[] = [];
  Date: any;
  dataReady: boolean = false;
  constructor(
    private homeService: HomeService,
  ) {
    Chart.register(Annotation)
  }
  faVolumeUp = faVolumeUp;

  public barChartLegend = true;
  public lineChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [];
  public lineChartPlugins = [];
  @ViewChild('fromInput') fromInput!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  @ViewChild('toInput') toInput!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  @ViewChild('filterSelect') filterSelect!: ElementRef<HTMLSelectElement>;
  @ViewChild('lineChart') lineChart!: BaseChartDirective;
  @ViewChild('lineChartCanvas') lineChartCanvas!: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  fromDateValue: number | null = null;
  toDateValue: number | null = null;
  filterDateValue: string = 'MONTHS';

  ngOnInit() {
    // Set default value for filterDateValue
    this.filterDateValue = 'MONTHS';
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Call onInputChange after the view has been initialized
    this.setDefaultDates();
    this.onInputChange();
  }
  setDefaultDates() {
    const today = new Date();
    const oneMonthAgo = new Date(today);
    oneMonthAgo.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 5);

    this.fromInput.nativeElement.value = oneMonthAgo.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    this.toInput.nativeElement.value = today.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  }
  onInputChange() {
    this.fromDateValue = this.getTimestampFromInput(this.fromInput.nativeElement.value);
    this.toDateValue = this.getTimestampFromInput(this.toInput.nativeElement.value);
    this.filterDateValue = this.filterSelect.nativeElement.value;

    this.getTranscriptionSummary(this.fromDateValue, this.toDateValue, this.filterDateValue);
  }

  getTimestampFromInput(inputValue: string): number | null {
    return inputValue ? new Date(inputValue).getTime() : null;
  }
  getTranscriptionSummary(fromTimestamp: number | null, toTimestamp: number | null, filterDateValue: string) {
    this.homeService.getTransactions(fromTimestamp, toTimestamp, filterDateValue).subscribe({
      next: data => {
        if (data.output_schema.status == 'Success') {
          this.dataTranscriptionChart = data.output_schema.data.chart.reverse(); // Reverse the dataTranscriptionChart array
          console.log(this.dataTranscriptionChart);
          this.dataTranscriptionSummaries = data.output_schema.data.summaries;

          // Transform data and update lineChartData datasets
          this.lineChartData.datasets = this.transformChartData(this.dataTranscriptionChart);
          console.log(this.lineChartData);

          // Force the chart to update
          this.lineChart?.chart?.update();

          this.dataReady = true; // Set the flag to true when the data is available
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      },
      error: err => {
        if (err.status == 401) {
          window.localStorage.clear();
          window.location.reload();
        }
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    });
  }


  transformChartData(dataTranscriptionChart: any[]): any[] {
    const datasets: any[] = [];
    const labels: string[] = [];

    for (const data of dataTranscriptionChart) {
      labels.push(new Date(data.date).toLocaleDateString());

      for (const detail of data.details) {
        const existingDataset = datasets.find(d => d.label === detail.status);
        if (existingDataset) {
          existingDataset.data.push(detail.value);
        } else {
          datasets.push({
            label: detail.status,
            data: [detail.value],
            backgroundColor: this.getBackgroundColor(detail.status),
            borderColor: this.getBorderColor(detail.status),
            // Add other properties as needed
          });
        }
      }
    }

    this.lineChartData.labels = labels;
    return datasets;
  }


  getBackgroundColor(status: string): string {
    // Return a color based on the status (customize as needed)
    switch (status) {
      case 'Done Deal':
        return '#84B19A';
      case 'Non-Transaction':
        return '#B8405E';
      // Add more cases for other statuses
      default:
        return '#000000'; // Default color
    }
  }

  getBorderColor(status: string): string {
    // Return a color based on the status (customize as needed)
    switch (status) {
      case 'Done Deal':
        return 'rgba(132,177,154,1)';
      case 'Non-Transaction':
        return 'rgba(184,64,94,1)';
      // Add more cases for other statuses
      default:
        return 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'; // Default color
    }
  }

  public lineChartData: ChartConfiguration['data'] = {
    datasets: [],
    labels: [], // Will be populated in the transformChartData method
  };



  public barChartData: ChartConfiguration<'bar'>['data'] = {
    labels: ['JULI', 'AGUSTUS', 'SEPTEMBER', 'OKTOBER', 'NOVEMBER', 'DESEMBER', 'JANUARI'],
    datasets: [
      { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: '  Deal Done', backgroundColor: '#3E3F5E', },
      { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: '  Cancel Deal', backgroundColor: '#84B19A', },
      { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: '  Split Deal', backgroundColor: '#F0C990', },
      { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: '  No Transaction', backgroundColor: '#2C688F', },
    ]
  };

  public barChartOptions: ChartConfiguration<'bar'>['options'] = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        align: 'end',
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
          padding: 40,
          boxWidth: 2,
          font: {
            size: 16,
            family: "Mulish",
            weight: '400'
          },
        }
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        }
      },
    },
  };

  public lineChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    elements: {
      line: {
        tension: 0
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        }
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        align: 'end',

        labels: {
          usePointStyle: false,
          boxWidth: 15,


          padding: 40,
          font: {
            size: 16,
            family: "Mulish",
            weight: '400'
          },
        },

      },
    }

  };

}
```

can you help me? I got stuck on this part, if you don't understand I can send the video